# Can anyone help with Font name?

Tags: fonts

ive spent the last 2 hours or so looking for this
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Laffayette Comic Pro](https://www.cufonfonts.com/font/laffayette-comic-pro) from cufonfonts.com

[image]